# Json Jackson - Using Alias for field names

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string which I want to serialize in a Java object, one of the properties in the json string doesn't match the name of field in the Java object, I know this can be fixed using the @JSONProperty as mentioned here - 
[Jackson annotation - How to rename element names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741134/jackson-annotation-how-to-rename-element-names)

But I don't have access to the source code of the Java object thus I can't add the annotation, is there a way to do this at runtime by providing some configuration code to the ObjectMapper? I am using Jackson version 1.9.

Thanks,

Comment: Jackson 1.9? That's prehistoric! Why not 2.6.x?

Comment: I know it's old but so is the application i am maintaining.

Comment: found the answer here - http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-mix-in-annotation.jsp, it's a better example than the link shared as the duplicate question

Comment: We can only link Stack Overflow posts as duplicates. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29391616/438154) gives a complete example.

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis - the accepted answer has the mixin declared and defined but how to register them with the objectMapper isn't provided that's why I had shared another link which provides the way to register the mixin with the object mapper as well.

Comment: It has both. Just scroll all the way to the bottom.